# What is Block ID (from cleos get info)?

Tags: cleos

I get this -

```
cleos get block 490684
```

```
{
  "timestamp": "2018-08-11T13:36:20.000",
  "producer": "eosio",
  "confirmed": 0,
  "previous": "00077cbb75a31d441793c5f6783366b953c48f43da7940a11b9ef9971d779d48",
  "transaction_mroot": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "action_mroot": "17ad7c545fa46f2717521a36fe334d7a6c14d71f46565a911f2b8a62234488b3",
  "schedule_version": 0,
  "new_producers": null,
  "header_extensions": [],
  "producer_signature": "SIG_K1_K2LsUdPM7HzQvY8pd58w2XdgfKe3x4jJraT7yF5cVeTSnAehW7tTyxHK6f6v5wL1L8umVWHjjPtfoazJHsSRin1iaf5odE",
  "transactions": [],
  "block_extensions": [],
  "id": "00077cbcfcecfabbc1adbb7015f8e0c7dd86a83bbb6c2b47e947eee6d85de8ea",
  "block_num": 490684,
  "ref_block_prefix": 1891347905
}
```

I am trying to interrogate the chain more to find what is being stored. I get an ID of

> 00077cbcfcecfabbc1adbb7015f8e0c7dd86a83bbb6c2b47e947eee6d85de8ea

What is that exactly?

Also in ethereum we have hashes in headers to maintain the reliability and then the Merkle tree. Is there something the same in EOS? Can I use this data such as "previous" and "action_mroot" to find out more what is being stored on the blockchain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is Block ID?

It's a hash of the block header according to **[`libraries/chain/block_header.cpp`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/45adb5e4cc6d550619fd27216b7c17f27c335272/libraries/chain/block_header.cpp#L22-L29)**:

```
namespace eosio { namespace chain {
   digest_type block_header::digest()const
   {
      return digest_type::hash(*this);
   }

   uint32_t block_header::num_from_id(const block_id_type& id)
   {
      return fc::endian_reverse_u32(id._hash[0]);
   }

   block_id_type block_header::id()const
   {
      // Do not include signed_block_header attributes in id, specifically exclude producer_signature.
      block_id_type result = digest(); //fc::sha256::hash(*static_cast<const block_header*>(this));
      result._hash[0] &= 0xffffffff00000000;
      result._hash[0] += fc::endian_reverse_u32(block_num()); // store the block num in the ID, 160 bits is plenty for the hash
      return result;
}
```

> Also in ethereum we have hashes in headers to maintain the reliability and then the Merkle tree. Is there something the same in EOS?

Yes, there are several such mechanisms:

- Each header refers to the ID of the previous block (see [here](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/45adb5e4cc6d550619fd27216b7c17f27c335272/libraries/chain/include/eosio/chain/block_header_state.hpp#L50))
- Each transactions specifies a block ID 
  (see [here](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/45adb5e4cc6d550619fd27216b7c17f27c335272/libraries/chain/include/eosio/chain/transaction.hpp#L32-L33) for code, and [here](https://github.com/EOSIO/Documentation/blob/master/TechnicalWhitePaper.md#transaction-as-proof-of-stake-tapos) for the whitepaper details: "*The EOS.IO software requires every transaction to include part of the hash of a recent block header*")
- EOS has a merkle tree for all actions in a block, a merkle tree for all transactions within a block, and a merkle tree of all blocks as detailed [in the whitepaper](https://github.com/EOSIO/Documentation/blob/master/TechnicalWhitePaper.md#merkle-proofs-for-light-client-validation-lcv) and explained [by Dan](https://steemit.com/eos/@dan/response-to-vitalik-buterin-on-eos).

[image: Figure from EOS paper showing how Merkle Trees are used in the blockchain]

*Figure from EOS paper showing how Merkle Trees are used in the blockchain*

> Can I use this data such as "previous" and "action_mroot" to find out more what is being stored on the blockchain?

You can use Merkle roots for generating Merkle proofs if you're operating a thin client and you want to verify if a transaction was included in an irreversible block without downloading the blocks. But, yes, you can use `previous` to query the block that the current block points to.

However, if you want to explore data in the blockchain, you can, more simply, query blocks by block number, which is a counter increcemented by 1 for every block in the blockchain. Example:

```
$ cleos -u https://api.eosnewyork.io get block 10000000
```

Would give you the 10,000,000th block produced along with all transactions included inside (but not all inline actions).

Comment: Thanks. I am still testing but when I get the nodes running I will test these data values.